# Clearing / Reseting user input within Tabs. C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tabs

I am trying to create a button that clears / resets the user input and then goes back to the start of the form.

My form has four tabs. The 'clear all' button is on the fourth tab.

```
 private void cmdClearAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      foreach (Control ctrl in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls) 
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    (ctrl as TextBox).Text = string.Empty;
                }

                if (ctrl is Label)
                {
                    (ctrl as Label).Text = string.Empty;
                }

                if (ctrl is ListBox)
                {
                    (ctrl as ListBox).Items.Clear();

                }

                if (ctrl is ComboBox)
                {
                    (ctrl as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = -1;
                }

          }
  }
```

The above code works but only on the last tab, What im trying to achive is to cycle back from 4th through to the 1st tab while clearing / reseting everything in the process.

I thought I could achive this by creating a for loop and adding the foreach above inside it but something is wrong.

```
    for (int i = 3; i <= tabControl1.SelectedIndex; i--)
    {
    foreach (Control ctrl in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls) 
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                (ctrl as TextBox).Text = string.Empty;
            }

            if (ctrl is Label)
            {
                (ctrl as Label).Text = string.Empty;
            }

            if (ctrl is ListBox)
            {
                (ctrl as ListBox).Items.Clear();

            }

            if (ctrl is ComboBox)
            {
                (ctrl as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
    }
```

I am trying to keep it as simple as possible as im new to programming and still learning. I have been on the problem for quite a while. If someone could provide me with an example of an easier way to do this or to point out some errors in my own code eg. "why it wont switch back to the previous tab and clear" that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your current `foreach` with something like:

```
foreach(TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
    foreach(Control ctl in tab.Controls)
    {
        // your "if" statements here...                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to alter your loop to include  all tabs rather than just the selected tab:

```
foreach (var tab in tabControl1.TabPages)
{ 
    foreach( Control ctrl in ((TabPage)tab).Controls)
    {
// your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second code example, it looks like you're getting a loop using i and then not doing anything with the variable at all.

Now keep in mind what I may be suggesting may not be exact - I haven't worked with winforms in a while - but what you'd REALLY want to do is use nested for-each loops if they work on forms the way they seem to for your first example. LewisT's answer gives you a general idea.

Be sure to set the "active" tab to the first one after the closing block of the outer for-each loop.

Finally - and this is a "Object Oriented Principle" rather than an answer to your question - I would extract this method out to where the click event for this button calls this method rather then doing everything inside of it. Consider the possibility that you may want a "clear all" button in other tabs for this form, or even in a different tabbed form. Rather than copying and pasting these ugly for loops and if statements, you can just call the method once in the event handler.

It'll make your code much more readable and you'll have more power over what your application can do.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like I get my answer late 20 mins but if you really want to clearing / reseting everything,you **should clear the ComboBox also?**

The solution is having another **higher layer** to loop with foreach, so we try to find out the relationship between **TabPage** and **tabControl1**. I tried to put `var` to declare the `tab` but the `tab` will become **object** type and cannot deal with `tab.Controls` later.

Therefore I check with [TabControl.TabPageCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and click the TabPage link in its description. I get the `System.Windows.Forms.TabPage` from Inheritance Hierarchy of [TabPage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). (I tried to show you how I get the correct class)

```
private void cmdClearAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //loop in TabPages collection in tabControl1
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        //loop in all controls in looping TabPage
        foreach (Control ctrl in tab.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                (ctrl as TextBox).Text = string.Empty;
            }

            if (ctrl is Label)
            {
                (ctrl as Label).Text = string.Empty;
            }

            if (ctrl is ListBox)
            {
                (ctrl as ListBox).Items.Clear();
            }

            if (ctrl is ComboBox)
            {
                //(ctrl as ComboBox).SelectedIndex = -1;
                (ctrl as ComboBox).Items.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I suggest to put the clear all button **out of the TabControl** and put it **somewhere in Form** to let the clear all button can commonly be seen and clicked even you are not in 4th tab?

Comment: Thanks for your help and spotting the mistake with the ComboBox.

Comment: I found the mistake because I try to build a same one to check my code functionality and it worked weird on ComboBox,haha